# When I start gounicorn.services, I get error 200/CHDIR. How can it be corrected?

Tags: django, nginx, gunicorn

gunicorn.service

```
[Unit]
Description=gunicorn daemon
Requires=gunicorn.socket
After=network.target

[Service]
User=root
WorkingDirectory=/var/www/botproject/
ExecStart=gunicorn --workers 5 --bind unix:/run/gunicorn.sock botproject.wsgi:application

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

/var/www/botproject/ - project folder

systemctl status gunicorn

```
● gunicorn.service - gunicorn daemon
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/gunicorn.service; disabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sat 2022-07-09 21:28:04 UTC; 3s ago
  Process: 83314 ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/gunicorn --workers 5 --bind unix:/run/gunicorn.sock botproject.wsgi:application > Main PID: 83314 (code=exited, status=200/CHDIR)

Jul 09 21:28:04 server.domain.com systemd[1]: Started gunicorn daemon.
Jul 09 21:28:04 server.domain.com systemd[1]: gunicorn.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=200/CHDIR
Jul 09 21:28:04 server.domain.com systemd[1]: gunicorn.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

I can't figure out what is causing the 200/CHDIR error

Answer (score 0):

I would start debugging by trying to run the ExecStart command manually, and see if that works (or what error you get):

```
$ cd /var/www/botproject/
$ sudo gunicorn --workers 5 --bind unix:/run/gunicorn.sock botproject.wsgi:application
```